# Using ruby Octokit, how do I return all the Pull Requests created since specified date

Tags: ruby, github, octokit

How do I get all the closed Pull Requests created since specified date time, using ruby octokit library? I tried  [`Octokit.GitHubClient.pull_requests`](https://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/PullRequests.html#pull_requests-instance_method), but this method doesn't accept `since` date, so, it pulls down all the PRs for the specified state.

Comment: Get all pull requests, filter them in your app code.  i.e. if you had 200, you get all 200 from the API, loop over each one and check for if the date matches your search criteria.  Not efficient, but it does work.

Comment: Currently I am doing that, but it is causing the application to run slow. So, I am looking for the alternate approach to improve the performance.

Comment: I haven't used the graphql API but perhaps it has some options for you? https://developer.github.com/v4/query/

Answer (score 0):

I found the following alternate option, `Octokit.GitHubClient.list_issues`.
Please refer to [this link](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/pengwynn/octokit/Octokit%2FClient%2FIssues:list_issues) for more detail.

example:
`Octokit.GitHubClient.list_issues(REPO, state: state, since: DateTime.now - 1)`
where `DateTime.now - 1` indicates the PR's created during previous 1 day period.